# sqlalchemy: I can`t delete the record from the table - violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**I get the following error if I add 'relationship':**

> (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column \"robot_id\" violates
>   not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (25,
>   P-SVWD5SX_cJXiUyDM41oHhcwkxYcSoG33vMrtXbbvI, null)

**MODEL:**

```
class Robot(Base, SQLTableJsonEncoder):
    __tablename__ = 'robots'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    hmac_secret = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('users.public_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    api_key = relationship('ApiKey', uselist=False)

class ApiKey(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'api_keys'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    robot_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('robots.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

**SERVICE:**

```
    async def delete_robot(self, user, robot_id):
        robot = super().get_first(mapped=Robot, user_id=user.public_id, id=robot_id)
        if not robot:
            raise NotFound(payload='Check your robot id')
        super().delete(robot)

        return robot.id
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for my case**: add setting 'cascade' in 'relationship':

```
class Robot(Base, SQLTableJsonEncoder):
    __tablename__ = 'robots'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    hmac_secret = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('users.public_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    api_key = relationship('ApiKey', uselist=False, cascade='delete')
```